# How to call webmethod from different website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, webmethod

I have website A which is done in ASP.NET and it has  in default.aspx

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public string GetCurrentTime(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
        + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

May we call that method somehow from another website B using C#?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can. it is a web service.

Comment: @Matt Thank you! Would you mind to provide an example of the code to do it, please? Is it possible to call it using WinForm app as well?

Comment: This provides an example with jQuery: https://trentgardner.net/net/asp-net-webmethods-with-jquery-and-ajax/

Comment: @Matt I mean can we call that method from C# code of other website? I mean to use WebClient of other approach..

Comment: @Matt Also, _"different web site"_ - so that link using script [will not work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Hth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *May we call that method somehow from another website B using C#?*

Yes, you can make `REQUESTS` to the endpoint using C#. Either `GET` or `POST`

**Simple GET request**

```
var endPoint = "http://domain.com/default.aspx";
var webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
using (var response = webReq.GetResponse()) {
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
        var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //Do whatever with responseString
    }
}
```

**Simple POST request**

```
var endPoint = "http://domain.com/default.aspx"
var data = "param1=hello&param2=world"
var webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
webReq.Method = "POST";
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
webReq.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
webReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
using (var requestStream = webReq.GetRequestStream()) {
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
using (var response = webReq.GetResponse()) {
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
        var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //Do whatever with responseString
    }
}
```

This is a simple way of doing it. More info at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) or [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) on the other hand. You can find example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015346/2436549) also.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, webapi is created intentionally to be called from inside the same website, another website, and from a whatever client (console, winform, wpf, mobile apps, and so on) using c# or another language.
.Net framework has avalaible various classes for calling webapi ex. HttpWebRequest, HttpClient or external libraries ex. RestSharp.